# Is there a GitX equivalent for Mercurial that allows command-line execution?

Tags: user-interface, command-line, mercurial, changelog, gitx

I really like being able to the command-line tool `gitx` from Terminal.app to open GitX and see the Git repository change log that I can scroll through, with nicely formatted diffs for each.

Mercurial is so similar that it would be nice to have a similar tool to just be able to view the commit log, changeset diffs with author, etc. like `gitx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [Murky](https://bitbucket.org/snej/murky/wiki/Home) is what I was looking for. In order to open up the current repository to view commits, changelogs, and authors, use:

```
alias murky open -a Murky
```

and then use the following to open up the current repo in Murky:

```
murky .
```

([Thanks to Jens Alfke for this info!](https://bitbucket.org/snej/murky/issue/171/terminal-integration))

So that I can more easily remember it, I also made an hgx alias to Murky in my ~/.bash_profile:

```
alias hgx='open -a Murky .'
```

That way I can just cd into a local mercurial repo directory and just type:

```
hgx
```

Comment: Though I'm not a non-open source fun, after using for some time MacHg, which doesn't have a diff browser, trying Murky which crashed right after launch on Mountain Lion and `hgx` which couldn't work, I'll suggest [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) which is free and at least has a diff browser.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [MacHg](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/) too.  It's a little nicer than Murky, IMHO.

hgtk is the best, in my opinion.  It's harder to setup and not as nice looking, but does much more than Murky or MacHg.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on this https://github.com/juancn/hgx

It's still kind of crude, but history viewing works fine. I couldn't get Murky to work on Lion, so I decided to build my own.